# MVC, custom framework: where to put controllers/actions

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller

in my framework, it looks this:

```
design
modules
  /links
  /files
    index.php -> view
    addNewItem.php -> action
    deleteItem.php -> action
```

in this paradigm, all controllers are in one file, I think it has better overview. But I saw other solutions to put all action on one controller, and files becames methods. Thats ok, but in the end we could get a big file. Which is one the preferred method, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVC pattern, you need to split you're current code between multiple controllers then each controller will have multiple actions, so you'll have multiple controllers not just one, each with multiple actions .

Let's say for example you have an Users area on you're site. You can make a Users controller witch has register, profile view and profile edit actions, and that's it. You'll allso need another controller for authentification ( login and logout actions ) , and so on witch seams to break you're code eaven better into pieces .

Next using the MVC pattern you'll allso need to write models for each "db entity", like a Users Model that defines a user, and if you go a bit further you can have a Users table mapper ( or a repository ) that implements all db queryes for basic CRUD ( and eaven more actions ) on the users .

For a better understanding i suggest you download a MVC framework allready built for php, smth easy that will explain better the concept of MVC and the advantages over the so called "classic" or "plain" php .

I suggest you try out the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) framework that as the documentation realy realy good for starter on MVC, or if you whant to go realy deep into to subject and get to know MVC eaven better do the [Zend Framework Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) turorial that should reveal a more in-depth view of what a MVC framwork arhitecture should contain and how it should be used.